# BETWEEN and JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, between

My aim is to, View all property viewers and planned viewings, in the year 2013.
I believe i have got 90% of the way to a solution, but at the moment, it does not work.

**Tables in use**

***yr_viewer***

```
Clientnum, CHAR(5), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1) 
Branchnum, CHAR(3), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 2)  
Prefferedtype, VARCHAR2(15),  nullable 
MAXIMUMRENT, NUMBER (17,2),  nullable 
Finished, NUMBER(1,0),  nullable
```

**yr_viewing**

```
propertynum, CHAR(5), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1) 
dateviewed, Date  nullable (format - 1-jan-2013)
Clientnum, CHAR(5), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 2) 
Staffnum,  CHAR(5),  nullable 
Comments,  VARCHAR2 (300),  nullable
```

**yr_Client**

```
Clientnum, CHAR(5), NOT nullable (PRIMARY KEY 1) 
Firstname Varchar2(20), nullable
Lastname  Varchar2(20), nullable
Address   Varchar2(50), nullable
Telephonenum Char (13), nullable
```

**My Query**

```
select distinct c.Firstname, c.Lastname, v.PropertyNum, v.DateViewed
 from yr_viewing, yr_viewer i
      inner join YR_VIEWING v
         on i.ClientNum = v.ClientNum
      inner join YR_CLIENT c
         on i.ClientNum = c.ClientNum
where dateviewed between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013'
```

Comment: What does 'it does not work' mean? You get an error, or not the expected results? Are you really doing an old-style join between `yr_viewing` and `yr_viewer` in the `from`, and then joining to `yr_viewing` again with a `join`? Which `dateviewed` is the `where` clause supposed to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some trouble around your joins. You're cross-joining `yr_viewing` with `yr_viewer`, then you're joining in `yr_viewing` again.

You don't pull any columns from `yr_viewer`, so leave it out of the query altogether. And you have no need to include `yr_viewing` twice. Try something like this:

```
select distinct c.Firstname, c.Lastname, v.PropertyNum, v.DateViewed
  from yr_viewing v
  inner join YR_CLIENT c on i.ClientNum = c.ClientNum
  where dateviewed between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013'
```

One more thing: your dates will only work if the Oracle `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to DD-MON-YYYY, which it normally isn't. Even if it is you shouldn't trust it. Better to use ANSI date literals and change your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
where dateviewed between DATE '2013-01-01' and DATE '2013-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
select distinct c.Firstname, c.Lastname, v.PropertyNum, v.DateViewed
  from yr_viewer VV
 inner join YR_VIEWING v
    on VV.ClientNum = v.ClientNum
 inner join YR_CLIENT c
    on V.ClientNum = c.ClientNum
 where TO_CHAR(dateviewed, 'yyyy') = '2013'
```

Edit: Double quotes (Suggestion by Alex)

Comment: Filtering on `to_char(dateviewed, ...)` would stop any index on that column being used.

Comment: He did not mention indexes, but this can be resolved with a function-based index.

Comment: Why not just use the date range though, and treat dates as dates? Admittedly the `between` the OP uses is only going to work if there is no time component (or anything on the last day of the year will be missed). This doesn't seem a great habit to get into. Adding an FBI seems quite a lot of overhead *if* there is already a normal index on the column. (It should also be `'YYYY'`, not double-quoted as `"YYYY"`; and arguably you should use `'2013'` it you're treating it as a string).

Comment: Thank you pointing the quotes. I am not complaining with you about not to use the date range. But it is a little more simple for a beginner not to deal with time values. And about the implicit conversion of 2013, I really think this is not a great issue. (But you are right)

Comment: And definitely if we think about a good model/query design, you must review the table design, the use of the distinct keyword and ...

Comment: No, just mentioned the 2013 in passing. But particularly for beginners I feel the potential downsides of things should be explained, otherwise they'll happily do this on all their own small tables with no consequences, and wonder why it causes a performance problem when they then do it on a real, large, query. The joins are obviously the issue here though, and I'm not arguing with what you've done there, so maybe this isn't the place to discuss this detail *8-)

Comment: Couple of points: (1) I think the `SELECT DISTINCT` was a crutch the OP used to get rid of dups in the original query due to the cross join, and (2) I'm not sure about the join to `yr_viewer`. It could be there to filter out any `ClientNum` values that aren't in `yr_viewer` but it may just be superfluous, due to confusion. Finally, if you want to use `=` instead of between, I'm pretty sure that `where TRUNC(dateviewed, 'YEAR') = DATE '2013-01-01'` will be optimizable without resorting to a function index, but I'm not at a place where I can verify that with a query plan.

Comment: I don't think that using TRUNC(dateviewed, 'YEAR') imply in not to resorting to a function index. Even if it does, will not the index have a worst performance than the fts? (Really curious :))

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I don't have any oracle experience, but I deal with mysql and sql server a lot so this may or may not work.

Are you sure you should be using inner joins instead of left joins?  Using inner joins will only display results showing people who are both clients and viewing.

Your statement seems a little funky too... You're doing an implicit join then following it by a explicit inner join of the same table...

maybe something like this would work better:

```
select distinct c.Firstname, c.Lastname, v.PropertyNum, v.DateViewed
from yr_viewing v
LEFT JOIN yr_viewer i
on i.ClientNum = v.ClientNum
LEFT JOIN YR_CLIENT c
on i.ClientNum = c.ClientNum
where dateviewed
between '01-jan-2013' and '31-dec-2013'
;
```